# How to export an image machine to another GCP account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I would like to import a machine image created in an account into a another google cloud platform account. could you help me?

Comment: What do you mean by a machine image? If you mean AWS EC2, you can check https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/import-existing-image#create_image_file and https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/import-existing-image#import_image

Answer (score 12):

There is a way to create an instance and a new machine image using a machine image from a different project.

I’ve reproduced this scenario in my own projects and I was able to use a machine image from a different project to create my instance, I’ve followed the next [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-images/create-instance-from-machine-image#create-instance-from-different-project)

I already created a machine image `my-machine-image` on my `machine-image-project-origin` and I granted permission to the service account `123456789000-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com` that is under the new project  `vm-project-destination`.

It is worth mentioning that my `machine-image-project-origin`  and my `vm-project-destination` are under different organizations and were created with different accounts.

To grant access to the `my-machine-image` that is stored in the project  `machine-image-project-origin` using the gcloud command-line tool:

```
gcloud beta compute machine-images add-iam-policy-binding my-machine-image \
    --project=machine-image-project-origin \
    --member='serviceAccount:123456789000-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com' \
    --role='roles/compute.admin'
```

You will obtain something like:

```
Updated IAM policy for machine image [my-machine-image].
bindings:
- members:
  - serviceAccount:123456789000-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/compute.admin
etag: BwXtXMjY8wZ=
version: 1
```

Then to use this image to create a new instance `my-instance`, in my new project `vm-project-destination` :

```
gcloud beta compute instances create my-instance \
 --project=vm-project-destination \
 --zone us-east1-b \
 --source-machine-image projects/machine-image-project-origin/global/machineImages/machine-image-to-share \
 --service-account 123456789000-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

And you will obtain something like:

```
Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/vm-project-destination/zones/us-east1-b/instances/my-instance].
NAME             ZONE        MACHINE_TYPE   PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP   STATUS
my-instance      us-east1-b  n1-standard-1               10.122.0.2   35.222.19.36  RUNNING
```

Then if you want, you can create a new machine image based in this new instance that we already created, that basically will be a copy from the machine image created in the original project.

On the other hand, I recommend you to review the following guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to provide a better context on what you are doing and what you want to achieve.

I hope you find this information useful.

Comment: great answer. I have been looking for this for a few days!

Comment: honestly, the linked documentations is very clear and more readable, because of the arguments placeholders and explanations.

Answer (score 3):

Start by looking at these docs: [Here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/managing-access-custom-images#share-images-between-organization)

This should give you an insight into sharing images across accounts.

Once you have properly shared access to the other account's image. I believe you could do something like:

`gcloud compute --project=destinationproject images create dest-image --source-image=src-image --source-image-project=sourceproject`